# How get unique and null entries from database?

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns: `label_value, language_value, language`. It's table for labels, where `label_value = "name"` of the label, language_value - translation of the label, language - id of language which is using. So, I need to extract `label_value`, `language_value` for English (language=45) and `language_value` for my language(language=24). Please, note, that not all English labels has translation to my language, but I need to extract all English labels and if the label has no translation to my English then it must return this label with NULL `language_value` for my language. So, I have made the following code:

```
SELECT e.label_value, e.language_value
FROM labels e, labels t
WHERE e.label_value=t.label_value AND e.language=45 AND t.language=24
```

I understand that it's not full and right query, because it hasn't returned not all English labels and returned some labels 2 times. Please, edit it. Thank you.

UPDATED:

Also I need that queries for locale satisfy the condition: t.approved='1' or t.user_id=123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `left join` to look up the optional local-language row:

```
select  eng.label_value
,       coalesce(loc.language_value, eng.language_value)
from    labels eng
left join    
        labels loc
on      loc.language = 24
        and eng.label_value = loc.label_value
        and (loc.approved = '1' or loc.user_id = 123)
where   eng.language = 45             
        and (eng.approved = '1' or eng.user_id = 123)
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot some details. Please, look at my updates in 3 minutes.

Comment: Why we need to add conditions to the both tables?

Comment: And also, please, now it works but I need one fix - now it returns NULL for all fields without language_value (for English), but I need that label_value for NULL labels is not null, i.e. labels without translation must contain label_value and english translation. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, first line should be `eng.label_value` instead of `loc.label_value`